# How to allow quotes to end after 'textwidth' on vim?

Tags: linux, vim, fortran

Since Fortran 77 only allows for 72 columns of text, vim highlights and *ignores* anything after line 72, which is fair enough since it will actually be ignored by the compiler.

The problem arises when I start mixing F90 and F77. The problem happens for `.f` and `.f90` files. I use vim 7.2 in Redhat 7.

I can have code that looks like:

```
string90 = "This is a string of more than 72 characters"
```

where the second quote is after the 'texwidth' marker. Vim ignores the second quote and treats the entire text as a string.

Can this behavior be modified somehow?

Comment: There is no such a thing as mixing F77 and F90 in one file. Is your file *free-form* or *fixed-form*? Which suffix does it have? Which version of Vim do you use?

Comment: free-form. I imagine vim understands it as fixed-form. However the problem also shows up in .f90 files (which I would think are understood by vim as free-form by default).
Edited for clarity.

Comment: So, which suffix for free form? Which Vim version? It does differ between versions and configurations. Which OS version you have?

Comment: Redhat 7, Vim 7.2. I'm not entirely sure what do you mean by suffix, but if you mean the file extension, .f90 and .f. I have the same problem in both

Comment: Suffix is anything appended to a file name. So yes, file extension is a kind of suffix if you want to play with exact words.

Comment: does `:h ft-fortran-syntax` (and any of the parameters mentioned there) help?

Comment: In part it did (thanks!), it must be an issue a lot of people come across since they actually have they have a piece of code for .vimrc to make sure .f90 is understood as free-form.

However, I still want to be warned when I am beyond the 72th column in a fortran 77 (.f) file without losing that second quote. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want .f files to be fixed-format and .f90 files to be free-format.  For that, you could add this to your .vimrc file:

```
" Set files with the extension .f to be fixed-format Fortran files, and .f90 be free-format
let s:extfname = expand("%:e")
if s:extfname ==? "f"
   let fortran_fixed_source=1
   unlet! fortran_free_source
elseif s:extfname ==? "f90"
   let fortran_free_source=1
   unlet! fortran_fixed_source
endif
```

You could get quite a bit fancier than this with different file extensions, of course, but this does what you were asking for and no more.

With regard to your last comment, Vim should tell you what row/column your cursor is on in the lower-right hand corner of the window.  This is the ruler option, which can be enabled with `set ruler`.